# How to access Class.typeName on Android api 21+

Tags: java, android, reflection

Class.typeName or Class.getTypeName() was added in Api 26 according to the Android docs. Is there a way to get the type name in some other fashion?

[image]

Comment: Just `getName()`? The method `getTypeName()` results in more readable names for array types, but you can easily assembly those names yourself, if needed.

Comment: @Holger okay that makes sense to me. I can use getName and derive the Type name from there. Thank you. Wasn't sure if I was missing something else that was simple. Feel free to mark that as an answer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method `getTypeName()` has been added in Java 8, to implement the [`Type.getTypeName()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/reflect/Type.html#getTypeName()) method that was added in the same Java version (as `Class` implements `Type`).

For non-array classes the result is the same as `getName()`. For exactly the same result, you can use

```java
static String getTypeName(Class<?> cl)
{
  if(!cl.isArray()) return cl.getName();
  int dimensions;
  for(dimensions = 0; cl.isArray(); cl = cl.getComponentType()) dimensions++;
  String name = cl.getName();
  StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(name.length() + dimensions * 2).append(name);
  for(; dimensions > 0; dimensions--) sb.append("[]");
  return sb.toString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Nohow.

`Class.getTypeName()` was added in java 8. Android supports java 8 since API 26.